# Как протестировать, что вызывается именно метод call в функции?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, mocha, sinonjs

Есть функция **applyAll**(она принимает функции(или **sum** или **mul**), и вызывает ее с любым переданным количеством аргументов), как протестировать что в ней используется и вызывается метод call, а не проверяется это допустим обычными if(что именно вызывать).
Использование метода call обязательно.

```js
const applyAll = (func, ...args) => {
    return func.call(this, ...args);
}
```

Код функций которые передаются в applyAl:

```
const sum = (...args) => {
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        result += args[i];
    }
    return result;
}

const mul = (...args) => {
    let result = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        result *= args[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ну передать туда какую-нибудь левую функцию и проверить результат. Все функции через  if не пропишешь. Или можно передать туда локально созданную функцию.

Comment: А какие еще способы есть вызывать изнутри `applyAll` переданную функцию? А если использует не `call`, а `apply` - это нормально?